# What is composition of convex and concave function?

Tags: convex-analysis, function-and-relation-composition

> Suppose that $f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is convex function and $g: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is concave function. What can we say about their composition $g\circ f$ and $f\circ g$? Are they convex or concave functions?

Thank you in advace !

Comment: Have you tried with some examples?

Comment: Yes, but I can't conclude with examples.

Comment: You cannot conclude anything without additional information; for instance, if $f$ is also nonincreasing, then the composition is concave.

Comment: See p. 84 of https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf

Comment: @LinAlg Many thanks for your useful reference!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint. Try $f(x)=e^x$ (convex) and $g(x)=-x^2$ (concave).

What about $f(g(x))=e^{-x^2}$?  Is it convex or concave? Check the [plot at WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20exp%28-x%5E2%29%20from%20x%3D-3%20to%203).

P. S. If we assume that $f,g$ are $C^2$ then
$$(f(g(x))'=f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x),\quad
(f(g(x))''=f''(g(x))\cdot (g'(x))^2+f'(g(x))\cdot g''(x)$$
So if $f''\geq 0$, $g''\leq 0$ and $f'\leq 0$ then $(f(g(x))''\geq 0$.

Comment: it's convex, right?

Comment: @Thomas Edison This means that you can't conclude nothing. You need additional hypothesis.  See my edited answer.

Comment: Or more generally if $\frac{f''(g(x))*(g'(x))^2}{-g''(x)} \ge f'(g(x))$ then it is convex, right?  (But just notice that this condition is much more specific because it depends on $g(x)$ rather than only on the derivatives).  $f'$ can be positive, but it just has to be small enough such that the hessian of $h$ is still positive semi definite right?

Comment: If the hessian of the composition is semidefinite positive, why do you conclude it is not concave nor convex?