Composition of convex and concave function
Let $f:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ be a convex increasing function. In general, the function $t\mapsto f(t^{1/2})$ can not be convex. But i wonder that if I have a condition such that
$$\exists C>0,\quad \forall t\ge 0,\quad f(2t)\le C f(t)$$
what can i say about the convexity of the function $t\mapsto f(t^{1/2})$?

There is some related information in the answers/comments on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1972469/what-is-composition-of-convex-and-concave-function?rq=1 but I don't think an explicit answer to your question.

@Steen82 I have added one more hypothesis. "increasingness of f"

It seems as if this can be either convex or concave, try $f(x)=x$ and $f(x)=x^2$.

A quick calculation shows that if you want your function to also be $C^2$, then it should satisfy:
$$2xf''\left(\sqrt{x}\right)>f'\left(x\right)$$
If you want your $f(\sqrt x)$ to be convex. I imagine that some version of Gronwall's inequality will give you better results
